# Fourier transform for a 2D curve

Tags: fourier-transform, transformation, plane-curves

I am stuck on the following problem about a Fourier transform of a 2D curve:

I have to calculate the Fourier transform (using 1D complex FT) (and the opposite of it) for a 2D curve z(t). The curve is in vector format. The input is:

n, (x1, y1) (x2, y2) ... (xn, yn)

where x is the real part and the y is the imaginary part of the "point" z=x+i*y (z(t)=x(t)+i*y(t), t is the current index in the vector format).

As per the problem's description, I have to generate simple random curves in vector format, then draw them and their frequency, calculate the Fourier transform and its opposite and check the result with the input image.

Do you have any suggestions what shall I do?
I think I know the general theory for each aspect of the above ones, but I am not able to put them together to solve the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the second example [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DiscreteTransforms%2fFourierTransform). This is it. [The article in Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) may be useful too.